# How mouse enter event work on disabled panel to display it?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have panel on main form in disabled state I want to enable it by mouse enter event. How can I?

```
private void pnlOne_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlOne.Enabled = true;
    pnlOne.Visible = true;
}
```

I try above one but it not working...

Comment: Disable the controls inside the panel, not the panel itself.  Simply iterate its Controls collection.

Comment: actually i have a video player to play video by default video is on stop position . now i want to play/pause/stop it by buttons which is in pnlOne panel and it disabled initially and i want when mouse enter in panel contained area pnlOne enabled and visible and when mouse leave it disabled once again...

Comment: Panel pnlOne is on Main Form and video is on inherited Form of main form by using DigitalRune.Windows.Docking DockPanel

Comment: @Anand actually i have a video player to play video by default video is on stop position . now i want to play/pause/stop it by buttons which is in pnlOne panel and it disabled initially and i want when mouse enter in panel contained area pnlOne enabled and visible and when mouse leave it disabled once again.. Panel pnlOne is on Main Form and video is on inherited Form of main form by using DigitalRune.Windows.Docking DockPanel

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Disabled** your control mouse event **wont get fired**. You cant do this.

Even if you enabled some other events,Check whether your  panel is in the front . Use bring to front in the designer. Reason could be  another container control is in the middle.

Comment: actually i have a video player to play video by default video is on stop position . now i want to play/pause/stop it by buttons which is in pnlOne panel and it disabled initially and i want when mouse enter in panel contained area pnlOne enabled and visible and when mouse leave it disabled once again... Panel pnlOne is on Main Form and video is on inherited Form of main form by using DigitalRune.Windows.Docking DockPanel

Comment: panel is on the front i know it. there is no problem

Comment: actually i have a video player to play video by default video is on stop position . now i want to play/pause/stop it by buttons which is in pnlOne panel and it disabled initially and i want when mouse enter in panel contained area pnlOne enabled and visible and when mouse leave it disabled once again... Panel pnlOne is on Main Form and video is on inherited Form of main form by using DigitalRune.Windows.Docking DockPanel

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `MouseMove` event on `Panel`'s parent control. In that you can check cursor position and if cursor is on `Panel`, you can enable `Panel`.

```
private void PANELS_PARENT_CONTROL_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Location.X > pnlOne.Location.X &&
      e.Location.X < (pnlOne.Location.X + pnlOne.Width) &&
      e.Location.Y > pnlOne.Location.Y &&
      e.Location.Y < (pnlOne.Location.Y + pnlOne.Height))
    {
      pnlOne.Enabled = true;
      pnlOne.Visible = true;
    }
  else 
    {
      pnlOne.Enabled = false;
      pnlOne.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i have a video player to play video by default video is on stop position . now i want to play/pause/stop it by buttons which is in pnlOne panel and it disabled initially and i want when mouse enter in panel contained area pnlOne enabled and visible and when mouse leave it disabled once again...

Comment: @user3540132 if you want `pnlOne` to be enabled/disabled, the code i provided will work. Or do you want the `buttons` to be enabled/disabled only?

Comment: Panel pnlOne is on Main Form and video is on inherited Form of main form by using DigitalRune.Windows.Docking DockPanel

Comment: how to enter in such event. in visual studio there is only mouse move event and you specified here PANELS_PARENT_CONTROL_MouseMove

Comment: By `PANELS_PARENT_CONTROL` i meant `pnlOne`'s parent control. If your panel is directly in the `form` then you need to write this `MouseMove` method for form. If it's inside another container like another panel or a layout then you need to write the method for that.